# Orthogonality Relations Problem with Sine

Tags: integration, orthogonality

Hello I could use some help understanding this problem. We are to prove that the orthogonality relation of this problem. Assuming m and n are integers with m not equal to n.
With a definite integral of 0 to pi (Sorry i don't know how to type the problem out properly on here)

∫sin(mx)sin(nx)dx = 0

Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint:** 
Use this identity:
$$sin(a)sin(b)={1\over2}[cos(a-b)-cos(a+b)]$$